# What happens to provability of consistency if we restrict semantics to $\omega$-models?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, incompleteness

If we restrict the semantics of a first order theory to only $\omega$-models of it, then if a theory doesn't have an $\omega$-model, then its $\omega$-inconsistent, now an $\omega$-model only have standard naturals, and cannot satisfy sentences not satisfied by the standard model of arithmetic. Now if a theory $\sf T$ is $\omega$-consistent, then any $\omega$ model of it will not satisfy $\sf \neg Con(T)$, so it must satisfy $\sf Con(T)$. We are left with two options:

> 1- any theory $\sf T$ sufficient to express its consistency in its language, that is $\omega$-consistent, and if $\sf T^*$ is $\sf T$ semantically restricted to $\omega$-models of $\sf T$, then $\sf T^*\vdash \omega$-$\sf Con(T^*)$,

or

> 2- there is a sentence true in ALL acceptable models of $\sf T$, that is not syntactically captured by it?

Which sentence is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question, but somewhat difficult to ask precisely. In my opinion things are made more difficult by bringing in the idea of syntactic entailment (= proof) too blithely. So let me be a bit more careful here:

Suppose we have a class $\mathbb{K}$ of structures. We can refine the usual entailment notion $\models$ between *sentences* to restrict attention to $\mathbb{K}$ as follows: $$\Gamma\models_\mathbb{K}\varphi\quad\iff\quad\forall\mathcal{M}\in\mathbb{K}(\mathcal{M}\models\Gamma\implies\mathcal{M}\models\varphi).$$ You can check a few basic properties of this notion. For example:

- If $\mathbb{K}$ consists of a single structure (up to isomorphism) $\mathcal{A}$ then $\Gamma\models_\mathbb{K}\varphi$ essentially reduces to the theory of that structure.
- More substantively, $\models_\mathbb{K}$ is not compact in general.

We can similarly restrict theories. Given a theory $T$ and a class of structures $\mathbb{K}$, let $$T^\mathbb{K}=\{\varphi:\forall\mathcal{M}\in\mathbb{K}(\mathcal{M}\models T\implies \mathcal{M}\models\varphi)\},$$ or using the notation above $T^\mathbb{K}=\{\varphi: T\models_\mathbb{K}\varphi\}$. Note that $T^\mathbb{K}$ is automatically deductively closed, so asking what $T^\mathbb{K}$ **proves** just amounts to asking what $T^\mathbb{K}$ **contains**. In particular, if $T=\mathsf{ZFC}$ (or similar) and $\mathbb{K}$ = $\{$$\omega$-models$\}$ then $T^\mathbb{K}\ni\mathsf{Con}(T)$ as you observe. This amounts to your option (1) ... but somewhat unsatisfyingly, since we've blatantly cheated in building $T^\mathbb{K}$ in the first place.

### Can we do better?

Ideally, we would find a natural to tweak, not the theory $T$ itself, but rather the *deduction relation* $\vdash$ used to analyze it. Put another way, we want to understand:

> Can we "algorithmically" (or "syntactically" or etc.) describe $\models_\mathbb{K}$ at least for certain choices of $\mathbb{K}$ (e.g. $\omega$-models)?

Note that the non-compactness of $\models_\mathbb{K}$ in general poses a problem here. At this point let's restrict attention to $\mathbb{K}$ = $\{\omega$-models$\}$.

*(If I were being historically accurate I'd probably mention something about "$\omega$-logic" here, but that's not my preferred narrative line, so:)*

It turns out that, necessary nonsenses of noncompactness notwithstanding, there is a very useful positive fact here:

> There is a single sentence in the logic $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ which captures the class of $\omega$-models of (say) $\mathsf{KP}$. Moreover, $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ has a "surprisingly-nice-all-things-considered" proof system.

The first sentence of the above is a good exercise. The second sentence is a deep result of Barwise, the so-called **Barwise completeness theorem**. It's also been misstated for simplicity: really, every *countable fragment* of $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ (but not the whole!) has a good proof system in an appropriate sense. In particular, already the **computable infinitary formulas** are enough to do the job. Note that the special case of Barwise completeness that we need in this instance is also due to Kreisel (cf. the section in [Ash/Knight's book](https://www.elsevier.com/books/computable-structures-and-the-hyperarithmetical-hierarchy/ash/978-0-444-50072-4) on **Barwise-Kreisel compactness**).

I've avoided giving details here, since they're a bit technical, but the overall point I want to make here is that **your case (1) can be construed as holding in a *non-trivial* way if we broaden our notion of proof a bit**.